Configure Mypy in settings.json in vscode to enforce type hinting
I am trying to make Mypy in VSCode enforce type hinting, but without success, I have tried following this previous post but the solution didn't work: Configure Mypy in VSCode to enforce type hinting
My vscode have the following python related extensions installed: "Mypy Type Checker", "Pylance", "Python", "Python Debugger". My .vscode/settings.json has
{
    "mypy-type-checker.importStrategy": "fromEnvironment",
    "mypy-type-checker.args": [
        "--disallow-untyped-defs=True",
        "--disallow-untyped-calls=True",
        "--check-untyped-defs=True",
        "--no-implicit-optional=True",
    ]
}

My directory looks like this
C:.
│
├───.vscode
│       launch.json
│       settings.json
└───src
    │   main.py

And my main.py only contains
def test(t):
    print(t)

but Mypy is not enforcing type hinting (no red line underneath the code)
How can I change my settings.json file such that Mypy enforces type hinting?

What happens if you remove =True?

I assume --disallow-untyped-defs=True is supposed to cause an error since test is untyped. I don't know the answer I'm afraid but I do know that unless you are working with an existing project that uses Mypy you should 100% use Pyright instead. It's orders of magnitude better.

Also a way to debug this is to go to the Output window and select Mypy from the drop-down on the right.

The only thing that was missing was installing Mypy in my python environment pip install mypy, I guess this was the missing piece for vscode "Mypy Type Checker" extension to use the arguments that was written in .vscode/settings.json
